# Get values only of select item vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using `vue-multi-select` package for multi-select in my app. And it stores and sends selected data in the following form:

```
[{name: volvo},{name: saab}, ...]
```

Or in simple term of HTML like:

```html
<select name="name" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Sends the text of selected items as values. But why do we want text ? We need ID's of selected items like this:

```html
<select name="name" multiple>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and get data like this format:

```
[{name: 1},{name: 2}, ...]
```

To get the result I wanted, I tried this:

```html
 <vue-multi-select
      v-model="form.includeds_id"
      search
      historyButton
      :btnLabel="btnLabel"
      :filters="filters"
      :options="options"
      :selectOptions="includeds"
  />
```

```js
import vueMultiSelect from "vue-multi-select";
import "vue-multi-select/dist/lib/vue-multi-select.css";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        multi: true,
        groups: false,
        cssSelected: option =>
          option.selected ? {
            "background-color": "#3f51b5"
          } : ""
      },
      filters: [{
        nameAll: "Select all",
        nameNotAll: "Deselect all",
        func() {
          return true;
        }
      }],
      includeds: [{
        id: "",
        name: ""
      }],
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        title: "",
        includeds_id: []
      })
    };
  },
  components: {
    vueMultiSelect
  },
  created() {
    axios.get("api/includeds").then(response => {
      this.includeds = response.data.map((obj, index) => {
        return {
          name: obj.name
        };
      });
    });
  }
};
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        multi: true,
        groups: false,
        cssSelected: option =>
          option.selected ? {
            "background-color": "#3f51b5"
          } : ""
      },
      filters: [{
        nameAll: "Select all",
        nameNotAll: "Deselect all",
        func() {
          return true;
        }
      }],
      includeds: [{
        id: "",
        name: ""
      }],
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        title: "",
        includeds_id: []
      })
    };
  },
  components: {
    vueMultiSelect
  },
  created() {
    axios.get("api/includeds").then(response => {
      this.includeds = response.data.map((obj, index) => {
        return {
          id: obj.id,
          name: obj.name
        };
      });
    });
  }
};
```

With my above stated code snippet I ended up getting this:

[image]

If I remove `name:obj.name`. I get the required ID's of selected items but text are not visible in select option.

Is there any way that text are visible in the select option and get the array of ID's of selected items ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your data to:

```
data = [
  {name: '1'},
  {name: '2'},
  {name: '3'},
  {name: '4'},
  {name: '5'},
]
```

And then add the labelName prop to get the user friendly labels.